# Issue with simple pointer syntax in my constructor body

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

So I'm pretty new in C++ and C languages in general and right now we have a project due in a few days that I'm nearly done with. I'm having several issues pop up every now and then however. Right now I am having an issue with proper assignment of class data members through my constructor.

Here is the code of the problematic class I'm trying to create:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Set{

private:

int *setOfElements;
int noOfElements;

public:
Set::Set(int *setArray){
    setOfElements = setArray;
    noOfElements = setArray->length();
}

int *getSetOfElements(){ return setOfElements; }
int getNoOfElements(){ return noOfElements; }

int findMedian();
int findMean();

};
```

The error appears in the second line of the constructor body. If I'm passing an int array as a parameter, then when I want to reference that parameter's length don't I have to use
-> instead of .  because the referent is a pointer object and not an object in the traditional sense?

Oh by the way, the error in VS 2010 says, "Error:Expression must have pointer to class type"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To answer the question in your comment on DeadMG's answer, even though it's not your primary question here:  In general you need to pass array lengths as well as pointers in C (and when using a C style in C++).  Null-terminated strings are an exception because you can discover the length as needed.
2. I agree with DeadMG in suggesting that you use `std::set` from the standard library instead of writing your own class.  You'll need to use a couple of other bits of the standard library as well to get the behavior of `findMedian` and `findMean`:

```
    #include <iterator>
    #include <numeric>

    std::set<int> s;
    // Initialize it...
    int mean = std::accumulate(s.begin(), s.end(), 0);
    mean /= s.size(); // Would you really want to use a double?

    // std::set is ordered, so finding the median is just iterating to the middle.
    int median;
    std::set<int>::iterator i = s.begin();
    std::advance(i, s.size() / 2);
    if (s.size() % 2 == 1) {
      median = *i;
    } else {
      median = (*i + *(++i)) / 2;
    }
```

Comment: Originally I tried to use the set class included in the standard library, but for whatever reason it couldn't find the set class within my call to std. Right now I'm trying to use your solution, but VS is still telling me "identifier set is undefined" when I try calling set s; when using namespace std;    or it tells me "namespace std has no member "set"  when I try to use std::set s;

Comment: I've also had a similar issue trying to access the vector class within the std library. It seem like this is an archive access issue... all I did was download and install the evaluation version of VS 2010. The std library is included in that right?

Comment: Nevermind, figured out the issue. I didn't realize that in addition to using the scope identifier to refer to one of std's included classes (either set or vector) that I also had to #include that class at the top of the file.   Once I add #include <set> intellisense shows me that  it can see the set member within the std namespace.

Comment: I just fixed HTML character entities in the code so that template parameters show.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is not a class and absolutely does not have a `length()` element. You are being corrupted by the evil forces of "Trying to copy and paste another language into C++". The only cure is "Learn C++".

Why would you even write your own set? The language comes with `std::set`.

Comment: Well, i guess I'm confused by pointers to primitive data types in C++ (and C as well) where char* equates to a string (char* is a pointer to the first char in the string and then traverses the rest of the char array) I've seen code that tells me that this is true for integers as well (and presumably any primitive). If I use int *arr  vs. int arr[] aren't the only differences between the two how they are allocated (dynamically vs on the stack (will be destroyed upon exiting scope))? This is a separate question and unrelated to my original post.

Comment: @Gthoma2: `char*` is not a string. `char*` is a pointer to one character. `std::string` is a string. You need to find some better learning material. There is no difference between `int*` and `int[]`. You should not pass arrays this way, it is hideously bad for many reasons. Use the Standard `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Comment: Again, I am trying to learn all of this currently, so I'm probably wrong here, but can't you regard an identifier bound to char* as a string? I know that, in reality, it's a pointer to a single character but can't you traverse the rest of the characters bound to that identifier? And if there is no difference between int* and int[] and both can be regarded as arrays, then the same would apply to a char* being the same as char[], and as we all know, Strings are just character arrays. So char* is a string. This is exactly what is confusing me and I realize that it's a C thing not a C++ thing.

Comment: Regardless, message received; I'll use classes within the std library.